# installation without CD

Tags: system-installation

Some time ago I installed ubuntu (I think it was version 10.04) in my mom's PC without CD and without having to reboot from flash drive. I don't remember how I did it, but I think I installed it using unetbootin.

I am trying to install the new 14 version here on my own PC (which does not have a cd drive) where now there is only windows 8, and I would like to have also both OSs. I tried unetbootin, but after running it and restarting computer, right after choosing the nunetbootin to restart from, i get the error:

file: ubnldr.mbr
status: 0xc000007b.

anyone can help?

Comment: Do you have a USB stick that's at least 8GB (4GB might work)?

Comment: another option is to create a 1Gb partition and to then put the Ubuntu ISO in that and boot into it from grub. Makes it easy to re-install to and easy to renew with a new OS.

Answer (score 1):

It was probably WUBI, but that only works (atm) with a Win7 installation or prior, according to the documentation:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide

If your mom's PC doesn't have a CD/DVD Drive, then it's probably the best way installing with an USB-Stick, see documentation here:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

While you are on windows 8
Download fresh ubuntu installation iso from:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Then download rufus: 
http://rufus.akeo.ie/downloads/rufus-2.5.exe

By using rufus put the iso on a USB 2-4 GB size at least

When you restart your pc you should boot from USB, you can do that by pressing F9 or F12 depends, and choosing USB.

Ubuntu should offer you Install alongside windows